# How to smooth elevation gain from GPS Points

Tags: javascript, gps, kalman-filter, elevation

I have a big problem here:

I have an array of gps datas and it's necessary to calculate some informations, I did it all except for the **total elevation gain** in the route.
There's an array like this `[825.23423, 827.39420, 828.19319, ...]` that storage the elevation of each gps point passed and I need to calculate the full sum.
The problem is that gps is not so accurate and sometimes gives some incorrect elevations, and it's making the sum get wrong.
I tried many ways to smooth the data, here are some:

- Set a minimum value to sum the elevation gain
- Get "sub-arrays" and made the media of them to sum the elevation gain after.
- Get "sub-arrays" and pop and shift the uncommon values to sum after that.
- And the actual way I mixed all, it got better but not even close to the perfect:

```
const getMediaFixed = (values: number[]) => {
      values.sort((a, b) => {
        return a - b;
      });
      values.pop();
      values.shift();
      const media = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / values.length;
      return media;
    };

    let last: number = elevations[0];
    let elevationSum = 0;
    // let countLimit: number = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < elevations.length - 5; i += 5) {
      let media: number;
      if (i <= elevations.length - 4) {
        media = getMediaFixed([
          elevations[i],
          elevations[i + 1],
          elevations[i + 2],
          elevations[i + 3],
          elevations[i + 4],
        ]);
      } else {
        media = elevations[i];
      }

      const temp = 0.75 * last + 0.25 * media;
      if (temp - last > 0) {
        elevationSum += temp - last;
      }
      last = temp;
    }
```

The point is that it's not working anyway.

Here's a site that works perfectly calculating from a GPX File (I couldn't find the contact to ask for help):
https://www.trackreport.net

I appreciate any ideas to improve the code!

Comment: Have you tried smoothing out the data points with something like a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)?

Comment: I tried today but it work for some types of routes and not to others.

Comment: Do you have sample data points for the altitude for routes that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I made it using the exponential moving average to smooth the array with elevations and then I used 1 meter to ignore the bugs!

Thanks.